# Why do E(X|Y)=Y and E(Y|X)=X imply P(X=Y)=1?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

> Suppose the $X,Y \in \mathcal L^1(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbf P)$ and that
>
> $\mathbf E(X|Y)=Y$ a.s. and $\mathbf E(Y|X)=X$ a.s.
>
> Prove that $\mathbf P(X=Y)=1$.

It is an exercise in *Probability with Martingales*.

Here is the hint in that book:

> Consider $\mathbf E(X-Y;X>c,Y\le c)+\mathbf E(X-Y;X\le c,Y\le c)$.

However, I have no idea what this hint means.

Below is my attempt:

I suppose that $\mathbf P(X=Y)< 1$, and without loss of generality I suppose $\mathbf P(X>Y)>0$.

So for some $\epsilon>0$, $\mathbf P(X-Y>\epsilon)>0$. Let $S:=(X-Y>\epsilon)$ be an event.

Then integrate on $S$: $\int_S(X-Y) \text{d}\mathbf{P}>0$.

By $\mathbf E(X|Y)=Y$ a.s. and $\mathbf E(Y|X)=X$ a.s., we have $\int_D(X-T)\text{d}\mathbf P=0$ for any $D\in \sigma(X)\cup \sigma(Y)$.

But it is not guaranteed that $S\in\sigma(X)\cup \sigma(Y)$. So I am not clear how to continue my proof...

Thanks in advance.